# Google People API no longer returns user details

Tags: google-people-api

I'm developing an application, and one feature includes displaying the profile photo of a Google user given their account ID (in integer form). This was working great in the past, but after taking a break from development of the app, the same API call no longer seems to work.

Endpoint:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/<USER ID HERE>?personFields=photos&key=<MY API KEY>
```

While this was previously returning a list of the user's photos, I am now only getting the response:

```
{
    "resourceName": "people/<USER ID HERE>",
    "etag": "<MASKED>"
}
```

I have not seen any notes about the API changing recently and so far have not found any alternative solutions.

I have verified that my API key is still valid and is authorized to use the People API in GCP console. Have tested the API call both from my application and manually via Postman with the same result.

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue for which I've created a ticket in Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/318079527. In my case the API does return CONTACT photos though (enabled by using the READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT source) but not PROFILE photos (normally enabled by using the READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE source). Those sources are used by default if no sources param is given though, so I would expect your response to contain at least a default photo. Have you tried through the API explorer using OAuth2 as well? https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get